# how to create class with generic types

Tags: c#, generics, xamarin.forms

I am returning values in a list and most of the values are strings and three images. I wanted to create generic class that would have values declared either as string or image source.

```
     public class DataField<T> where T : new()
        {
           public T Value { get; set; } 
            
           public string Description { get; set; }
           
           public int Quality { get; set; } 
            
           public int FieldIndex { get; set; } 
    
           public enum FieldDataType { get; set; } 
    
        }
```

Then  I have tried to assign each type string or Image source as

```
     public static DataField<ImageSource> BarCode =>
               new DataField<ImageSource>()
               {
                   FieldDataType = GraphicType.BarCode, // ENUM
                   FieldIndex = 1,
                   Quality = 100
               };
```

but I am getting error:

> The type 'Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource' must have a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic class 'dev.nubeo.recognition.abstractions.Models.DataField'

And the same with string. Is there a way to achieve what I need? I am very new to generics, apologies if this is complete nonsense

Comment: It sounds like you have a `where T: new()` constraint on `DataField<T>`, but there's no evidence of that in the definition you have provided. Please provide the correct definition.

Comment: Now we have the correct definition, I suggest you remove `where T: new()` (since you're not using it anyway) and your problem will be resolved.